# Log4j2's PatternLayout skips patterns in brackets

Tags: java, log4j2

I can't seem to be able to print the following pattern properly `[%level] %message%exception%n`. Everytime I invoke it, it only prints the `%message` and the `%exception` (and the `%n`). What do I need to do to have the `%level` being print between brackets?

Here's my Log4j2 configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%level] %message%exception{short}%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

And here's a unit test that shows the issue:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.junit.Test;
public class Log4j2Test {
  @Test public void testLogging() {
    LogManager.getLogger().info("expecting [INFO]", new RuntimeException());
  }
}
```

The result of this test is the following:

```
Running Log4j2Test
expecting [INFO] java.lang.RuntimeException
    at Log4j2Test.testLogging(Log4j2Test.java:19)
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.453 sec
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Edit: here's the `pom.xml` I used. Just change the version to 2.1 or 2.2, it's the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>be.fror</groupId>
    <artifactId>tmp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: try setting the root level to all

Comment: Come on... I give a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and you tell me to try something that doesn't even work?

Comment: what do you mean come on

Comment: I mean that I make the effort to trim everything unnecessary to simplify the task of the helpers and you just didn't care and gave an answer that 1. proves you haven't tested my issue and 2. proves you haven't tested your answer. Also, I say that it doesn't work because I took the time to try your suggestion, without success. Finally, I believe you'd really want to check the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) website to know more what I'm talking about.

Comment: i just made a guess so dont freak out

Comment: I've just tested this and it works on my side (exactly the same config file and Logger call). Which version of Log4j are you using? (mine is 2.0.1) Are you sure that Log4j uses this configuration? : have you tried to modify this pattern (e.g. add "foo" in it) to ensure that it's really this Pattern that is used?

Comment: I've had this issue in both 2.1 & 2.2. I have only one configuration file, I specifically created an independant project to test this issue. I tested this with 2.0.1 and I have the issue as well.

Comment: Okay, I found some additional information: when I run it in NetBeans, I get the issue. When I run it in the terminal, I have not issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a NetBeans issue, not Log4j2: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=251448